# Show whether $f(x,y)=x^{\alpha}y^{1-\alpha}, 0 \le \alpha \le 1$ is convex, concave or neither.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Show whether $f(x,y)=x^{\alpha}y^{1-\alpha}, 0 \le \alpha \le 1$ is convex, concave or neither, considering only the strictly positive orthant $\mathbb{R^2}_{++}$

My attempt is to find the Hessian matrix, and determine if it is positive semi-definite. I derived:

\begin{bmatrix}
(y^{1-\alpha})(\alpha)(\alpha-1)(x^{\alpha-2}) & (\alpha x^{\alpha-1})(1-\alpha)(y^{-\alpha})\\
(1-\alpha)(y^{-\alpha})(\alpha)(x^{\alpha-1}) & (x^\alpha)(1-\alpha)(-\alpha)(y^{-\alpha-1})
\end{bmatrix}

The eigenvalues are: $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2 = (\alpha-1)(\alpha)(x^{\alpha-2})(y^{-\alpha-1})(x^2+y^2)$

Now my confusion lies when trying to determine when the second eigenvalue is positive. $(\alpha-1)(\alpha)(x^2+y^2)$ are always positive so we can disregard these terms; $\lambda_2 = x^\alpha y^{-2} y^{-\alpha}y^{-1}$. Then we can disregard $x^{-2}y^{-1}$ as these are always positive. Thus we are left with, $\lambda_2= (\frac{x}{y})^\alpha$. I am having trouble determining from here, what values of $\alpha$ make $\lambda_2$ positive.

Comment: $(α−1)$ is not always positive. In fact it is almost always negative, only nonnegative for the single value of $α = 1$ where it is equal to zero

Comment: the factors (α)(x^(α−2))(y^(−α−1))(x^2+y^2) are always positive. That leaves that the second eigenvalue is positive if (α-1) is positive, which for α in [0,1] is never the case. At best, there is one value of alpha for which the second eigenvalue is nonnegative